# AWS Policy to Read/write RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, devops

In my scenario , I want a policy that will allow reading and writing of `abc-database-backups/rds/postgresql-backup` on S3? We'll want the my servers to have that access added.

Is creating a role and attaching it to the servers is best or adding a key to the server?

I tried this :

```
aws iam create-policy \
     --policy-name rds-s3-integration-policy \
     --policy-document '{
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                    "Resource": "*"
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:ListBucket",
                        "s3:GetBucketACL",
                        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "s3:GetObject",
                        "s3:PutObject",
                        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/key_prefix/*"
                }
            ]
        }'
```

I would be very grateful for any help, as my experience in this field is somewhat limited.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify your question. Are you wanting PostgreSQL on which platform (RDS / EC2) to have access to a specific S3 bucket? This tends to be done with a role. Please include the role definition. It's easier to show the role and policy directly rather than the CLI command to create them.

Comment: Yes, I want  PostgreSQL on RDS  to have access to a specific S3 bucket. what is your best advise here , Is creating a role and attaching it to the servers is best or adding a key to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [service linked role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.ServiceLinkedRoles.html) for RDS to provide access to S3 and any other named resources you require. Ensure the RDS instance has this role. You should also read [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html) about importing S3 data into RDS PostgreSQL using an extension.

I've adapted some CloudFormation infrastructure as code I have which should set up a role. You'll want to modify the permissions and bucket name to suit your requirements. It should work as-is but I did have to massage my existing code so if it doesn't work 100% please edit the post or comment so I can edit it.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Role for RDS

Resources:    
    RdsS3IntegrationRole:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Role
        Properties:
            RoleName: RdsS3IntegrationRole
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                    -
                        Effect: Allow
                        Principal:
                            Service:
                                - rds.amazonaws.com
                        Action:
                            - sts:AssumeRole
                
    RDSS3IntegrationPolicy:
        Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
        Properties:
            Roles:
                - !Ref 'RdsS3IntegrationRole'
            PolicyName: RDSS3IntegrationPolicy
            PolicyDocument:
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                        Action:
                            - s3:GetObject
                            - s3:ListBucket 
                            - s3:PutObject 
                        Resource:
                            - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*'
                            - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::bucketname'
                    - Effect: Allow
                        Action:
                            - kms:Decrypt
                            - kms:Encrypt
                            - kms:GenerateDataKey
                            - kms:ReEncryptTo
                            - kms:DescribeKey
                            - kms:ReEncryptFrom
                        Resource:
                            - !Sub 'arn:aws:kms:ap-southeast-2:${AWS::AccountId}:key/*'
```